# Opendaylight (odl) ovs-vsctl not found error

Tags: karaf, opendaylight, openvswitch

I am following this tutorial: https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Getting_started

I am trying to use the following code in opendaylight using karaf

```
ovs-vsctl show
```

But the command window says `Command not found: ovs-vsctl`

I have installed all the necessary libraries and the local host server (`http://localhost:8181/dlux/index.html`) is running fine. But somehow odl can't find ovs.

Can anyone tell me what's the error? I am running win 8.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this command outside of karaf terminal.

Firstly, you should have ovs(Open Virtual Switch) or Mininet installed, and then create one or two open switches.
Basically, you  started the SDN controller in karaf, and now in the step you are encountering problem, the switches need to be assigned ODL controller as their manager.

Answer (score 0):

You must check also that ovsdb is already installed in karaf. 
For that, try to execute the next command:

```
feature:list | grep ovsdb
```

That command will display all the ovsdb components/features that are available in your karaf distribution. The third column will indicate you if a given component is already installed or not (if you see an X, that means that the component is installed). If you want to install a component/feature:

```
feature:install <name_of_the_feature>
```

After that, try to execute it outside of karaf, as Sidhant01 has indicated you before. 
Try to do it with sudo:

sudo ovs-vsctl show.

If you want to configure ovsdb in an active mode:

```
tools-vm:~$ sudo ovs-vsctl set-manager tcp:127.0.0.1:6640
tools-vm:~$ sudo ovs-vsctl show
98d8cf7a-44b1-4b02-a60c-7d832409d06f
  Manager "tcp:127.0.0.1:6640"
      is_connected: true
  ovs_version: "2.0.2"
```

Cheers